# Placing images stored on your computer in a question

Tags: support

I want to place an image that is stored somewhere on my computer hard drive in a question, but the website only tells you how to insert pictures that are from websites. I tried copying and pasting the image but that doesn't work. The picture I am trying to upload is a JPEG image of a circuit built in multisim. Can anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 4):

When you click image it lets you choose between "from my computer" or "from the web". There is a selection right above where you place path.

[image]

Comment: @Kortuk- This is great! Thanks!

Comment: See also - recursion

Answer (score 1):

I presume that by "the website" you mean https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help?  That's probably a little more involved than you initially wanted to learn.  Most of the functionality is available by just hovering over the editor toolbar. (Note: A lot of information on this site is contained in hover text!):

[image: screenshot of wmd-button-row]

Hover over the icons for information on their function (if it's not obvious from the appearance).  There are also keyboard shortcuts for each function.  In order, they are:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> - Bold
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> - Italic
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> - Insert Link
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> - Block Quote
- <kbd>CRTL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> - Code Block
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> - Upload a Graphic from computer or website
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> - Ordered (numbered) List
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> - Unordered (bullet) List
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> - Heading
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> - Horizontal Line
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> - Undo
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> - Redo

For the text formatting options, you can either select the text that you want to change, or click the button and it will begin the formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kevin. This will help me with how I present my answers.