# FAQ or wiki on how to best embed a schematic

Tags: support, schematic

Could we have a FAQ or wiki on how to best embed a schematic?

The discussion on this question: [How Arduino Power supply works](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26484/how-arduino-power-supply-works) shows that the process can be confusing, particularity to newcomers.

Having good, readable schematics to accompany questions seems like such a big benefit that it would be in everyone's benefit to explain to people how to do it in the best way.

**EDIT:** Based upon Kellenjb's comment, I would like to broaden my question. I was not really asking if a schematic should be in color or B&W, rather I am asking for general guidance on a simple and easy way for a newcomer to create a simple schematic and attach it to a question.

My thought is *any* schematic is better than trying to describe a circuit in just words, and further I think (I could be wrong) that many newcomers don't really know how to create and attach one with their question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the discussion on the question you linked is really a great example. I don't see any reason why a schematic can't have color on it unless it causes it to actually be unreadable, which I have never seen.

I am not sure there is even a problem so it is hard for me to support an FAQ discussing something that isn't an issue. If people really think there needs to be something, I would rather it be more broad talking about how to post good images, not just schematics.

After your edit, [here is a wiki](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics) that has already been made to talk about how to make schematics. As far as attaching it to a question, there is already a question [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/883/placing-images-stored-on-your-computer-in-a-question) that explains how to do so. It seems to be very rare that someone doesn't know how to upload an image once they get the rep to be able to do so.